# Server Side Post request Firebase Functions React Form Actions

Tags: reactjs, firebase, api, google-cloud-functions

When I click the Button on frontend, I get directed to localhost/create-account-hosted but renders "Cannot POST".
Postman however shows the **Endpoint works just fine.**

Not sure what I got wrong here.

Backend endpoint on Firebase Functions folder

```
app.post("/create-account-hosted", async (req, res) => {
  try {
  var account = await stripe.accounts.create({
    type: "custom",
    requested_capabilities: ["card_payments", "transfers"],
    business_type: 'company',
    
  })

  var accountLink = await stripe.accountLinks.create({
    account: account.id,
    success_url: "https://example.com",
    failure_url: "https://example.com",
    type: "custom_account_verification", 
    collect: "eventually_due",
  });
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
  res.status(400);
  res.send({ error: err });
  return;
}

res.send(accountLink.url)
```

Front End code form POST request for server side redirecting.

```
<div className="beASeller">
                    <form
                        type="submit"
                        action="/create-account-hosted"
                        method="POST"
                        class="stripe-connect white"
                    >
                        <button> Seller Signup</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
```

Comment: Hi @Jed Lancer, where is your front-end deployed?

Comment: Hello, the front end is on localhost:8100. Since this was slightly a Stripe thing, I was helped by the Stripe discord as well and this has been solved, I'm updating the answer now to this question

Comment: @MarcAnthonyB please feel free to suggest other solutions or point out any tips as well

Answer (score 1):

Since my Postman was querying the Firebase function itself e.g. https://uscentral1.myfunction.cloudfunctions.net/create-account-hosted, I needed to do the same with my front end code.

```
<div className="beASeller">
         <button                        
         action="https://uscentral1.myfunction.cloudfunctions.net/create-account-hosted/"
         class="stripe-connect white"
         >
         </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a HTTP client. For this case, we'll use `Axios`.

There are a bunch of additional options which you can take advantage when making a request using `Axios`, but here are the most common ones:

- **baseUrl** - If you specify a base URL, it’ll be prepended to any
  relative URL you use.
- **headers** - An object of key/value pairs to be sent as headers.
- **params** - an object of key/value pairs that will be serialized and appended to the URL as a query string.
- **responseType** - If you’re expecting a response in a format other than JSON, you can set this property to arrayBuffer, blob, document, text, or stream.
- **auth**: passing an object with username and password fields will use these credentials for HTTP Basic auth on the request.

You may refer [**here**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios), for setting up `Axios` in your project.

After installation, you can now use `Axios`. Please see sample code below:

```
import axios from 'axios';

axios.post('https://uscentral1.myfunction.cloudfunctions.net/create-account-hosted', {"body":data}, {
    headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
    }
  }
)
```

Please also check **steps 2 - 4** on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65860388/firebase-function-doesnt-execute-when-called-from-domain) and see if it also helps.